# Как ускорить передачу изображений?

Tags: java, изображения, сеть, сокет, tcp

делаю программу,которая передает изображения от клиента к серверу.
Эти изображения должны передаваться быстро,что-бы создавалось видео на сервере.
Я использую сокеты для этого.При тестировании программы на localhost изображения передавались с низкой скоростью.При тестировании на другом пк в локальной сети(wifi),скорость заметно падала.
Примерно так я передаю изображения:

```
while(true){
        //capture screen
        BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(image);

        //send captured screen to the server
        try{
            oos.writeObject(imageIcon);
            System.out.println("image sended");
            oos.reset();//clear objectOutputStream cache
        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        //wait for 100ms to reduce network traffic
        try{
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }catch(InterruptedException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Как можно ускорить передачу и есть ли смысл использовать DatagramSockets?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

1. Поднять сокет на сервере на TCP протокол
2. Поднять сокет у клиента на TCP протокол
3. Направлять байты в сокет сервера
4. Получать байты из сокета клиента

Если будут проблемы с реализацией, помогу с кодом.

Comment: Спасибо,код точно помог бы